# how to get SHA1 hash without downloading for a blob block stored in azure storage in node js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to do file validation using sha-1 hash and i need sha-1 hash value without downloading block from azure storageblob.Please,help me with code sample (Node js).

```
  //I am using this method to upload BlockBlob (@azure/storage-blob npm)
  blockBlobClient.commitBlockList(arr).then(async (res)=>{
                  console.log('res',res);         
              }).
              catch((err)=>console.log(err))
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
      hash.setEncoding('hex');    
      hash.update(filechunk);
      hash.end();
      let val= hash.read();
      //Here stageblock will check userspecifiedmd5value with server calculated value if it matches then it will proceed further or else throw error
      let stageRes = await blockBlobClient.stageBlock(blockID,DATA,fileSize,{transactionalContentMD5:Buffer.from(val,"hex")});
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob storage stores the MD5 hash (not SHA1) of the blob automatically as property while putting the blob. You can retrieve blob properties using the same blob SDK you are using (@azure/storage-blob). Unfortunately there is no out of the box support for SHA1 hash without downloading/streaming the blob if that's what you specifically need. If MD5 works for you then below snippet will get it without downloading the blob.

```
const props = await blockBlobClient.getProperties();
const md5 = props.contentMD5.toString('base64');
```

Note: When you upload blob (file or bytes), storage calculates the MD5 hash. But since here you are uploading by breaking into blocks, storage does not calculates the MD5 hash of the full blob because each block is written separately.

Comment: Okay sir.I understood.But how to can i set contentmd5 property.Could you please help me with the sample code.

Comment: I am getting contentMD5 value undefined.So,Could you please help me with the code sample how to set contentMD5 property in commitblocklist() method.Thank you for helping me sir.

Comment: You do not need to set contentMD5 while uploading blob. As I mentioned, it's automatically set by Azure Storage. You can retrieve that using the code snippet I shared above. Is that returning undefined? If your JS function is not async then use the below snippet: 
    blockBlobClient.getProperties().then(props =>{
                const md5 = props.contentMD5.toString('base64');  
            })
            .catch((err)=>console.log(err));

Comment: Yes,sir.I am doing same.but,its returning undefined sir.

Comment: blockBlobClient.commitBlockList(blockidarray).then(async (res)=>{
                  
                  }).
                  catch((err)=>console.log(err))
              });
               blockBlobClient.getProperties().then((props)=>{
                 let prop= props.contentMD5.toString('base64');
                 console.log('prop',prop);
              })

Comment: it is returning undefined sir.

Comment: contentLength: 4906,
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  etag: '"0x8D81E8F1DEDEB38"',
  contentMD5: undefined,
  contentEncoding: undefined,
  contentDisposition: undefined,
  contentLanguage: undefined

Comment: I am getting this error"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined."

Comment: what's the version of @azure/storage-blob in your package.json?

Comment: "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.1.1"

Comment: I am using this version sir

Comment: also, can you share how the blockBlobClient is initialized in your case. At my end it's working fine when I tried.

Comment: I called blockBlobClient.getProperties() inside block of BlockClient.commitBlockList ..Still same undefined.Could you please share me your code?.

Comment: const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("99999");
    var containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("mycontainer");//Establishing ContainerClient
    const blockBlobClient = await containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("song1.mp3");

Comment: //here i am saving staging data
 await blockBlobClient.stageBlock(blockID,filedata,fileSize);      blockBlobClient.commitBlockList(BlockArr).then(async (res)=>{
                     blockBlobClient.getProperties().then((props)=>{
                   console.log(props);
                 let prop= props.contentMD5.toString('base64');
                 console.log('prop',prop);
              }).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
                  }).
                  catch((err)=>console.log(err))
              });

Comment: Sir,I am doing same thing.But getting undefined contentMD5 property.I will share my code sir.Thank you once again for helping me sir.

Comment: Sir,Could you please help me with the complete code.what you are doing at BlockBlobClient.stageBlock((blockID,size).Please help me with complete code sir.Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I think I got the problem now. When you upload blob (file or bytes), storage calculates the MD5 hash. But since here you are uploading by breaking into blocks, storage does not calculates the MD5 hash of the full blob because each block is written separately.

Comment: Yes,sir.Exactly.That was the issue and  i don't have idea how to calculate md5 hash ..Could you please help me with the sample code?